# How do I send money from one smart contract to another?

Tags: solidity

I know how to make a smart contract send money to an address, and I know how to send money from an address to a smart contract in Remix, but when I try to have one contract send to another my require function catches it and it doesn't work.  I have a second contract, and here is the code that's not working:

```
function sendMoney(uint amount) public{
        (bool success,) = casino.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Fail!");
    }
```

casino is defined as a specific address of another smart contract earlier in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send ethers to another smart contract the address should be payable
or you can cast the address on the following way:

```
(bool success,) = payable(casino).call{value: amount}("");
```

additionally the other smart contract should have a [fallback](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function) or a [receive](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#receive-ether-function) function in order to be able to receibe the funds

Answer (score 0):

To build up a bit on Javier's answer, here are 2 simple contracts.

```
contract Receiver {

    receive() external payable {}
}

contract Sender {

    Receiver public receiver;

    constructor(address payable _receiverAddress) payable {
        receiver = Receiver(_receiverAddress);
    }

    function preferedMethod() external returns(bool){
        (bool success,) = payable(receiver).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        return success;
    }

    //Works but not recommended
    function transferEth() external {
        payable(receiver).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    //Works but not recommended
    function sendEth() external returns(bool){
        bool success = payable(receiver).send(address(this).balance);
        return(success);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the receiver contract has a receive payable function, and the Sender contract has 3 different methods of sending Eth.

I think 'call' is the preferred method now but do realize that 'call' opens the door to reentrancy hacks.

And here is a link of Solidity by Examples that might help: https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/

Hope this helps!